# Problem with accents in Exchange 2010 smtp messages

Tags: exchange

Installing brand new Exchange 2010 server. Everything is working pretty good, except that when we send email from the smtp server directly (not from a windows client like outlook), french accents are being replaced with other (random) characters.

We are experiencing this problem with email sent from php and different app that we developped in house.

I can reproduce the problem by connecting with telnet to the smtp server on port 25.

I've tried searching on the net, but haven't found much.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Are your scripts/tests sending unencoded accented characters in the message header (subject lines for example) or in the body of the message without declaring a character set?

If so, I wouldn't expect that to work (at least not reliably) since once you get outside the standard 7-bit US-ASCII range the interpretation of codes depends on the charset.

Assuming you've not managed to sort this yourself do you have examples of messages as sent and as received? That's likely to shed light on how/why they're getting mangled.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following links:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310794.aspx

and

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125174%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, already visited those links, and it didn't work out.